# I can't figure out why my PrismaDB isn't working

Tags: mysql, prisma

I ran `npx prisma db push` and I got a really weird error:


[image]

Here is my `schema.prisma`: [code](https://github.com/Crazygird/discord-app/blob/main/prisma/schema.prisma)